# How can I export module pattern function to another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript files and would like to export the file with module pattern to another file.  The file with module pattern, I would like to export only public members.  When I try to execute the test, it says that "Calculator is not a constructor".

file: calculator.js

```
var Calculator = function(){
    var total = null;

    return {      
        add: function(x,y){
            total = x + y; 
        },

        getTotal: function(){
            return total;
        };

        display: function(){
            console.log(total);
        }
    }
}
```

second file: testCalculator.js

```
const calculatorObj = require('calculator.js');

describe("Calculator test suite", function(){
    var calculatorObj = new Calculator();

    it('Verify sum method', function() {        
        try{
            calculatorObj.add(5,5);                

            //assertive
            expect(10, calculatorObj.getTotal());
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You forget to export your calculator: ```module.exports = function(){```

Comment: do I have to list all the function names that I want to export?  and in "testCalculator.js" file, do i need to use "import" or "require()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working, because you need to export something before consuming it.

Add this code to make it work

```
module.exports = function(){
    var total = null;

    return {      
        add: function(x,y){
            total = x + y; 
        },

        getTotal: function(){
            return total;
        };

        display: function(){
            console.log(total);
        }
    }
}
```

> do I have to list all the function names that I want to export?

Yes, you have to export all things you want to import later. Or you can export one single object with all code you need.

> do i need to use "import" or "require()"

For Node.js, `require` is common practice. Latest Node.JS supports `import` construction, but, at least for now, using require is preferable.

For browsers, you will use `import` notation.

And your function is not a classical constructor, please, take a look into the [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) notation

Comment: when I have only one JavaScript fille "calculator", i was able to do something like "let cal = new Calculator();     cal.add(5,5);     cal.display();

Comment: When you have 1 file, you don't need to do import/export. You are free to use all written code. But this is not something good, really. File with 10 000 lines is a big ball of mood.

Comment: thanks.  After following your suggestion, I can see the public members when debugging the code, but somehow intelliSense does not show the members.

Comment: Use typescript or jsDoc if you want to have good IntelliSense https://jsdoc.app/tags-example.html

Comment: thanks, i will check them out.  I'm using Visual Studio Code though.